# Why does ssmtp work with sudo but not without?

Tags: cron, ssmtp

I am a Ubuntu novice. I've set up ssmtp.

If I run

```
echo "mail test" | sudo ssmtp -vvv xxxxxxxx@domainname.com
```

it works. Without sudo it doesn't. It gives `Authorization failed 535 Incorrect Authentication`

So what difference is `sudo` making ?

If I can resolve this it will help with a bigger problem of why I can't get a shell script to work - it comes up with the same error.

**testscript**

```
ssmtp.conf :-
root=xxxxxxxx@domainname.com
mailhub=auth.smtp.vvvvvvv.co.uk
UseTLS=YES
FromLineOverride=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
AuthUser=xxxxxxxx@domainname.com
AuthPass=pppppppp
rewriteDomain=domainname.com
AuthMethod=LOGIN
TLS_CA_File=/home/username/cert.pem
```

**testscript  shell script**

```
#!/bin/sh

TODAY=$(date)

echo "Test script running $TODAY" >> /home/username/Documents/testfile.log

if ssmtp xxxxxxxx@domainname.com < testscript.txt

then

  echo "Test script Complete" >> /home/username/Documents/testfile.log

else

  echo "Test script Failed" >> /home/username/Documents/testfile.log


echo "Test script ended" >> /home/username/Documents/testfile.log
```

**testscript.txt**

```
To:xxxxxxxx@domainname.com
From:xxxxxxxx.domainname.com

Subject:Mail Test
MIME-Version:1.0

Content-Type:text/plain
```

Auto email test

Answer (score 3):

Users are not supposed to run `ssmtp` directly; use a proper mail user agent such as `mail`, `mailx`, or `mutt`:

```
echo Test | mailx -s Test foo@bar.baz
```

Comment: My aim here is to email out when overnight, weekly and monthly backups running as crontab tasks have successfully completed.  Which of the mail agents you suggest would be easiest / most suitable for this simple requirement ?

Comment: All three can be used from the command line in basically the same way, as I showed above.

Comment: I have installed mailx and tried the command as shown (with correct email address) and I am still getting 535 INcorrect Authentication data

Comment: Ignore last comment. It is now working thanks although I have yet to try it under crontab.